sum of sequences of random variables with limiting distributions (Convergence in distribution)
Suppose $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are random variables (with finite second moment) satisfying
\begin{align}
&\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_iY_i\overset{d}\longrightarrow N(0,a)\tag{1}\\
&\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\overset{d}\longrightarrow N(0,b)\tag{2}\\
&\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i\overset{d}\longrightarrow N(0,c)\tag{3}
\end{align}
for some constants $a,b,c>0$.
I am hoping to establish the convergence in distribution result for
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_iY_i+X_i+Y_i)\tag{4}
\end{equation}
perhaps via showing the joint convergence of the three, i.e. (1), (2), (3). Perhaps I am overlooking something, but I cannot possibly think where I might be able to start. Any advice?
I mean, is there anything, apart from the Cramér–Wold theorem, one can use to show the joint convergence and establish the convergence in distribution for (4)?

Are the random variables $X_i$ and $Y_i$ independent? How did you establish the original weak limits? If that's the case, you might want to consider using characteristic functions to establish your limit.

Thanks Jorge. X_i and Y_i are not independent to each other, Y_i is a martingale difference, and X_i is some complicated function of Y_i.

while the pair $(X_i,. Y_i)$ is dependent, we need to know whether there are independence between $(X_i, Y_i)$ and $(X_j, Y_j)$ when $i \neq j$. Also, are these pair having the identical distribution? And when establishing the original convergence, are we applying some sort of CLT?
